# Android SDK, Output Stream from client to server doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

So I was just seeing if I could build a dead simple chat application, and im facing a problem... I have the server running on my pc and the client on my phone, Once the client has connected to my pc I can then go to my pc and write as many  messages as I want and they will appear on my phone (client), but when I try to send a message from my phone it will only send one message then no more, any ideas?

**Server:**

```
static OutputStream out;
static InputStream in;
String name = "Server";

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Server On");

    //Server
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            new Main().start();
        }}).start();
    //Scanner for text input
    new Main().scrnn();
}

public void scrnn(){
    Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(lol.hasNext()){
        try {
            out.write((name + ": " +lol.nextLine().toString()).getBytes());
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    scrnn();
}

public void start(){
    try{
        ServerSocket sok = new ServerSocket(42069);
        while(true){
            Socket sk = sok.accept();
            in = sk.getInputStream();
            out = sk.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer);
            String recievedData = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println(recievedData);
            out.write(recievedData.getBytes());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And the client:(android phone)**

```
OutputStream out;
InputStream in;
Socket sk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = new Object[]{"Thanks for using Monsterchat"};

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sk = new Socket("10.0.0.9", 42069);
                sk.setKeepAlive(true);

                out = sk.getOutputStream();
                in = sk.getInputStream();

                //This will send fine but if you look at the button onclick it wont send that :(
                out.write((name + " Joined the group!").getBytes());

                //This is how i can send constant messages from the server though
                listenForData();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        out.write("succ".getBytes());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

    public void listenForData() throws Exception{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    in.read(buffer);
    final String recievedData = new String(buffer);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Update listView with new message
            buildList(recievedData);
        }
    });
    //Repeat
    listenForData();
}
```

Sorry there's a lot of code, and also nothing gets output in the logcat that looks wrong

Comment: have you tried to debug?

Comment: yes, that did absolutely nothing to be honest, have any other idea?

Comment: are you sure that `out.write((name + " Joined the group!").getBytes());` is executed successful?

Comment: Yes, I could see the reply from the client on my pc

Comment: is your `listenForData` executed? Do you receive response from server

Comment: Yup, I could send texts and they would instantly appear on the phone, but not the other way around... It works if I open a new socket every time I want to send a message from my phone to my pc, but I need a constant flow, I can't be wasting resources, plus the phone gets quite warm when doing so :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while(true){
        Socket sk = sok.accept();
        in = sk.getInputStream();
        out = sk.getOutputStream();
    Dr    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        in.read(buffer);
        String recievedData = new String(buffer);
        System.out.println(recievedData);
        out.write(recievedData.getBytes());
```

That loop is wrong. After one received message the server drops `sk` and will go waiting for a new client.

You better try;

```
        Socket sk = sok.accept();
        in = sk.getInputStream();
        out = sk.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while(true){
        int nread = in.read(buffer);
        String recievedData = new String(buffer, 0, nread);
        System.out.println(recievedData);
        out.write(recievedData.getBytes());
```

Comment: Wow good eye you got there! Thanks, now it works perfectly! Although I needed to reset the `buffer` every time in the while loop to fix the weird extra text from the previous message. Thank you again for the help though! :)